# Can I implement half of OAuth?

Tags: oauth

I'm writing a web service, in which I'd like users to be able to generate OAuth client tokens for other people, essentially. So, instead of people coming to my site and signing in and being given a token, they'd have to be given a token generated by an existing user of my site. This is just key-based authorization, it sounds like to me.

Is this a dumb idea? Are there other things that make more sense in this scenario?

Comment: What your describing is not oAuth.

Comment: but isnt it sort of half of oauth? like, given the access tokens, isnt the rest the same?

Comment: I don't believe there is such a thing. You can't follow half a protocol. oAuth and all of it's parts make it the oAuth protocol. What you are doing coule be considered oAuth-inspired or perhaps oAuth-like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, you can generate the token and distribute it any way you want, and then require that it is used in transactions that follow the OAuth protocol. There is no law forbidding it.

- Confusing? Yes.
- Weird that someone other than me can authorise an application to use my private resources? Yes.
- Possible? Yes.

I don't know what your use case is, it may be that it makes perfect sense to you, but it does seem very counter-intuitive to me.